# JAVA - if condition not working properly on parameter

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat, date-format

I am trying to make a submit button that saves the user input when it is clicked and I am having a problem with the if condition part. What I want to happen is when the user clicked the button after 10:00 o'clock (based on system time) the Report on database would be "Late" else report would be "Not Late". But every time I clicked the button even the system time is before 10:00 it always says "Late". How to fix this?

Code:

```
try {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO studentregisterlogin" + "(SSN, TimeIn, TimeOut, Report)" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studentlogin", "root", "");
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, tfSerialNumber.getText());
    pst.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    pst.setString(3, " ");

// My Problem is this Condition 

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try { 
        if (date.after(dateFormat.parse("10:00"))) {
            pst.setString(4, "Late");
        } else if (date.before(dateFormat.parse("10:00"))){
            pst.setString(4, "NotLate");
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    pst.executeUpdate();
    //updateTable();

} catch (SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`,  `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the line **dateFormat.parse("10:00")**.

This actually parses the date as **Jan 1st 1970**. So, if you compare it against the current time it will always be after. That is the reason your if condition is always true.

Instead, you can fetch the current hour using the below code.

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //hour is in 24 hour format.
```

You can use this value to compare it with your 10:00 (10 if AM. 22 if PM) o'clock limit. Make sure you convert into 24-hour format before comparing.

So, it would be something like

```
if(hour > 22){
  // Too late
}else{
  // Not late
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working now but how to add minutes in the condition. For example, I change the late time to 10:35?

Comment: You could use the same method. Use Calendar.MINUTE and get the current minute.

Comment: Okay, Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Octavio - You can get rid of all these kind of error-prone complexities and overheads by using the modern date-time API (`java.time` API) as suggested by Ole V.V.

I highly recommend you go with his advice.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

If you’re sure that the date is the same and you only need to compare the time of day, the following is what you need. Let’s first declare a constant to hold your threshold of 10 AM:

```
private static final LocalTime DUE_TIME = LocalTime.of(10, 0);
```

Now the comparison goes:

```
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    if (now.isAfter(DUE_TIME)) {
        System.out.println("Late");
    } else {
        System.out.println("On time");
    }
```

When running just now (12:42 in my time zone), I got this output:

> Late

`LocalTime` is a time of day without date (and without time zone or UTC offset). It goes from 00:00 to 23:59:59.999999999. So every time from 00:00 through 10:00 will be considered on time and all other times of day late.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: I'll try this one too. Thanks!